# Looking for clarification for a proof that relates injectivity and surjectivity with linear(in)dependence and generating sets

Tags: linear-algebra

There's a proof in my book which says the following:

> Assume $V$ and $W$, two $K$-vectorspaces. $B$ is a basis for $V$ and $\{w_b|b\in B\}\subseteq W$ a subset of $W$. Consider the linear mapping:
>   $g:V\rightarrow W:\sum_{b\in B}\lambda_bb\rightarrow\sum_{b\in B}\lambda_bw_b$
>   Then the following is true:
>   (i) g is injective iff $\{w_b|b\in B\}$ is a linearly independent set in W.
>   ... (similar statements for surjectivity and bijectivity)

My question is, what is meant by "$\{w_b|b\in B\}$"? What is meant by the fact that the index is an element of the basis for $V$?

Comment: What is meant is the family $\left(w_b\right)_{b \in B}$ (indexed by the set $B$). A basis is understood best as a family, not as a set.

Comment: It simply means that for each vector $v$ of the basis $B$, there exists a vector $w$ in $W$ that gets associated to it. In order to remember which $w$ is associated to each $v$, one simply writes the name of the vector as a subscript. Hence $w_b$ is the vector of $W$ that gets associated to $b\in B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means a fixed association $b \to w_b \in W$ for all $b \in B$.